# Has the US president been uninvited to an international event before?

Tags: united-states, international-relations, president, 2023-israel-hamas-war

Is it unprecedented for the US president to be uninvited to an international event like President Biden was on October 17 this year (his [summit with Arab countries was canceled at very short notice, because of the outrage at the hospital explosion](https://www.bnnbloomberg.ca/biden-summit-with-arab-leaders-canceled-jordan-minister-says-1.1985996)), or there are comparable precedents?

Edit: please interpret "international" as happening outside the U.S.A.

Comment: That doesn't sound like an uninvite as the entire event was cancelled and not just some people uninvited.

Comment: It was canceled out of outrage, and Biden was the only Israel's allies' representative at the summit, so I have used "uninvite". Would you suggest a better phrasing?

Comment: The reason something is cancelled doesn't change that it was cancelled. I think the question is okay, just that the example isn't the president being uninvited from something rather an event cancelation.

Comment: ChatGPT says no as the baseline answer.

Comment: Does the state of union address count as 'international'?

Comment: @Questor - it happens on the US land, so probably not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

During the [U-2 crisis](https://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/u-s-soviet-summit-meeting-collapses):

> Tensions from the incident were still high when Eisenhower and Khrushchev arrived in Paris to begin a summit meeting on May 16. Khrushchev wasted no time in tearing into the United States, declaring that Eisenhower would not be welcome in Russia during his scheduled visit to the Soviet Union in June. [...] Eisenhower’s planned trip to Moscow in June was scrapped.

[Much] more on that [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/09592296.2021.1961488)

> Planning was at an advanced stage when Khrushchev withdrew the invitation, leaving a body of material outlining what the ten-day trip would have entailed. [...]